# Multiple add to cart products in one button using link

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to "add to card" products using URL like "https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=ProductID" but the problem is I will pass an array of ProductID that was in my javascript code. I would like to ask if we can pass an array of productID in "add-to-cart" parameter?

I tried this solution below:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.order-btn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected_items = $('.selected_items').val();
        items = selected_items.split(',');

        for (x of items) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url() . '/?add-to-cart=' ?>' + x,
                method: 'get',
                async: true,
                success: function (res) {
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('food-and-catering-cart'); ?>";
                }
            })
        }
    })
</script>


<input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items" value="1,2,3,4)">
<div class="order">
    <p class="hope_btn1">
        <a class="order-btn" href="<?php echo site_url('food-and-catering-cart'); ?>">ORDER NOW</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

When I checked the cart it only displayed two items and sometimes 1 item only.

Comment: you have to use`POST` parameter instead of `get`

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I already tried it but the results still the same :(

Comment: how are you getting the input element <input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items" value="array('1','2','3','4')">

is it static? and  how are you getting the array of product IDs

you can make the input element as per no of IDs like <input .... name="items[]"..>
  @Alvin

Comment: it is not static the value that I entered is just an example. but the value still the same which is became an array

Comment: ok, I can see you are using ajax call inside for loop. For multimple items, It will be redirected to "site_url('food-and-catering-cart');" at first time of execution. I guess @Alvin

Answer (score 0):

change input value like this

```
<input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items" value="1,2,3,4">
```

then using explode() function breaks the input string into an array in php.

[how to use explode function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Comment: you could not pass array through url. If you want to pass multiple inputs with same input name, then change your input name like this "items[]" and assign create multiple value with the same name input. "                                       <input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items[]" value="1">                  <input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items[]" value="2">                      <input class="selected_items" type="text" name="items[]" value="3">" on more.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a form with a **Submit** Button and it will pass the form inputs through url:

```
<form id="add-to-cart-form" method="get" action="youraction" >
  <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="2" />
  <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

And then you can get that in $_GET **super global** like an array

```
$GET['products'] =  Array(1,2)
```